# installing only one js file using npm install

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json, npm-package

This is snippet of `package.json` file

```
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery.cookie": "^1.4.1",
    "jquery.autocomplete": "^1.2.0"
  }
```

the `npm install` command will do the following:

- Package A

  - node_modules

    - jquery.cookie

      - some files (`jquery.cookies.js, tst/, etc`)

I just want to install the `jquery.cookies.js` files, in package A, I don't want other directories and files. What combination need to be  mention for `"files:[]"`?